# conditional row indexing in r

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr

I have a large dataset and I want to create a new column that sets a value based on a condition. Here is an example:

```
x <- tibble(
  x1 = c(rep("a", 3), rep("a1", 3), rep("a2", 3))
)
```

I would like a new column that that identifies all of the same values of column one.  The end result should look like the following:

```
x <- tibble(
  x1 = c(rep("a", 3), rep("a1", 3), rep("a2", 3)),
  x2 = c(rep(1, 3), rep(2, 3), rep(3, 3))
)
```

Is there an easy way to do this?  Maybe in dplyr?  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

A `data.table` option using `.GRP`

```
> setDT(x)[, x2 := .GRP, x1][]
   x1 x2
1:  a  1
2:  a  1
3:  a  1
4: a1  2
5: a1  2
6: a1  2
7: a2  3
8: a2  3
9: a2  3
```

or `rleid` (thank @akrun's comment)

```
> setDT(x)[, x2 := rleid(x1)][]
   x1 x2
1:  a  1
2:  a  1
3:  a  1
4: a1  2
5: a1  2
6: a1  2
7: a2  3
8: a2  3
9: a2  3
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `match`

```
library(dplyr)
x <- x %>% 
         mutate(x2 = match(x1, unique(x1)))
```

---

Or do a grouping and get the group index with `cur_group_id`

```
x <- x %>% 
        group_by(x1) %>%
        mutate(x2 = cur_group_id()) %>% 
        ungroup
```

Comment: Perfect!  That worked like a charm, thank you.